# Getting n slip number based on the number of times in a month a slip has been created

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, window-functions

Hi Guys so here is my table, I need a slip number for the slipno collom that is based on the number of times the empno has a slipno in a month.

To try and better explain here is my table

```
----------------------------------
SLIPNO | EMPNO    | DATE         | 
----------------------------------
123    | 0151450  | 07/OCT/17    |
234    | 0151450  | 14/OCT/17    |
345    | 0151460  | 10/OCT/17    |
456    | 0151466  | 05/OCT/17    |
567    | 0151466  | 01/OCT/17    | 
----------------------------------
```

and need a result like this

```
-----------------------------------------------
SLIPNO | EMPNO    | DATE         | SLIPNUMBER | 
-----------------------------------------------
123    | 0151450  | 07/OCT/17    | 1          |
234    | 0151450  | 14/OCT/17    | 2          |
345    | 0151460  | 10/OCT/17    | 1          |
456    | 0151466  | 05/OCT/17    | 1          |
567    | 0151466  | 01/OCT/17    | 2          |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Windowing Function](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).

```
SELECT SLIPNO, EMPNO, DT, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPNO ORDER BY DT ASC) AS SLIPNUMBER
FROM SLIPS;
```

[DB Fiddle Test](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31462d3fc5fabeb957570dce88459823) to show an example.

Also note that you should not use `DATE` as a column name, as it is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).